# How can I make an SKPhysicsBody for this image using CGPath?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am trying to make an SKPhysics body for this SKSpriteNode using a CGPath polygon.

[image]

The problem is that when I check for a collision between this node and the player node, the didBeginContact method is executed even though they did not touch each other. I believe their is something wrong with the coordinates but I cannot see the polygon lines, which makes it difficult for me too see the accuracy of the lines.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
 let triangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Triangle_ZigZag")
 let trianglePath = CGMutablePath()

 trianglePath.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: triangle.size.width, 
                                 y: triangle.size.height),

                                CGPoint(x: triangle.size.width, 
                                 y: - triangle.size.height),

                                 CGPoint(x: -triangle.size.width,
                                 y: triangle.size.height / 2)])

 trianglePath.closeSubpath()
 triangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: trianglePath)
```

Can someone please help me figure out what am I doing wrong ?

Thank You

Comment: turn on  showPhysics = true in your GameViewController to see the physics outlines

Comment: hello, I turned it on but the outline does not appear. Is there a way I can get the exact coordinates of the 3 points of the node outline ?

Comment: you need to show better code snippets. Are you adding triangle to the scene? what is triangle2?

Comment: Sorry Triangle2 is supposed to be triangle I fixed it in the question. Yes the triangle is node and its being added to the scene. I can't get the SKPhysicsBody to match the shape of the Triangle. I am trying to do it by using a CGPath. I can't use the texture to get the physics body because It makes the scene lag a lot when the node is added to the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI physics lines are green, so a green sprite probably isn't the best choice you can't see the lines very well.

your sprite has a centre anchorPoint or an anchorPoint of (0, 0) by default. Therefore your physics points need to take that into account. top right corner would be half the width from centre and half the height from centre etc. You have full width from centre and full height from centre, that is the issue.

```
trianglePath.addLines(between: [CGPoint(x: triangle.size.width / 2, y: triangle.size.height / 2), CGPoint(x: triangle.size.width / 2, y: -triangle.size.height / 2), CGPoint(x: -triangle.size.width / 2, y: 0)])
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, I like keeping the actual body in relative coordinates so that I may be able to reuse it, and use `copy(using transform: UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>?)` to translate the path based on the anchor point